# Xcode 6.1 Link Binary with Libraries; Framework not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode6.1

I'm having issues getting a framework to work when checking out my project from a repository. If I check out the project I get a build error:

```
 'Module SQLite not found'.
```

I went into Build Phases and checked that everything was properly set. I tried deleting the entry under **Link Binary with Libraries** and then re-adding it. This is where the issue occurs. When I go to add the framework, again, it doesn't show up.

For other parts of the Build Phase: **Target Dependencies** and **Copy Files** I can delete the entries and re add them and the framework still shows up no problem.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to post photos but the links to the Xcode screenshots can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yijJw.jpg

I'm assuming it's a **configuration error** because all of the required files are in the repository as well as the checkout folder. So if anyone could assist me in figuring out what needs to be changed, that would be greatly appreciated.

*Note I'm using Xcode 6.1 and the framework in question is SQLite.swift [found here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).*

Comment: You have to import libsqlite3 in "Linked frameworks and libraries" into your project.

Comment: The SQLite framework already does this